# Cannot connect to database server-MySQL problem

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1045

I tried everything to solve this problem but it's still not solved.
I keep getting this error:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using
> password: NO)

I'm pretty sure I'm entering the password correct. Also when trying to open the database in MySQL workbench I'm getting this:

Error:

[image]

Pls if you have a solution explain it detailed,thank you.

Comment: "using password: NO"  indicates, you have not entered a password ...

Comment: even if I enter the password,I get the error

Comment: Without you showing us what you actually are doing, nobody is able to help you. We don't know what privileges or passwords you set. Judging from the two different errormessage, you are either entering no password at all or the wrong password, Or root@localhost isn't allowed to connect to the database at all.  You may be able to reset yor password with these instructions: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-windows-excerpt/5.7/en/resetting-permissions-windows.html

Comment: I wish I could explain you but my English is not enough for that but I'll try: I was testing connection but it always gave me errors,I don't think my password is wrong but I don't know how to change it either (and when I tried to I didn't understand instructions)

Comment: I see, but it's also quite hard for to help if we don't know what you did. Where did you get the password from, you are trying? Did you set it at the installation? And especially if you dropped out in the middle of the password reset process, it's quite hard to know, what the current status of your installation is.

Answer (score -1):

Check if the mysql path has been created and add to the system

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. If the MySQL binary itself would not be callable, the error message would be a different one

Comment: it's been created and added

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).